# Solve $f '(x)=f '''(x) + x$ under initial conditions

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I know that:

$$\begin{align}
f(0)&=4 \\ 
f '(0)&=0\\
f ''(0)&=3 \\ 
f '(x)&=f '''(x) + x
\end{align}
$$

I need to find $f(x)$, how can I solve this?

This is obviously a differential equation, I began by finding $f(x)$ which is $f(x) = f''(x) + (x^2/2) + c$ but I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: Where are you having trouble?

Comment: I edited the OP, check that please

Comment: Why don't you solve for $f'(x)$ first? And only then for $f(x)$? Let $g = f'$

Comment: Have you tried Laplace transforms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider first the differential equation $g(x)-g''(x)=0$, whose solutions are of the form
$$
g(x)=ae^x+be^{-x}
$$
A particular solution of $h(x)-h''(x)=x$ is obviously $h(x)=x$, so the general solution of
$$
g(x)=g''(x)+x
$$
is
$$
g(x)=ae^x+be^{-x}+x
$$
and so, taking $g=f'$, we have that the general solution to your equation is
$$
f(x)=\int (ae^x+be^{-x}+x)\,dx=ae^x-be^{-x}+\frac{x^2}{2}+c
$$
Now substitute the initial conditions.

Comment: I don't get the first statement, can you explain it to me or post a link where that is explained please?

Comment: @matt95 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients

Comment: Shouldn't the first statement be g(x) = (c1 e^(r1 x)) + (c2 e^(r2 x)) ?

Comment: @matt95 The roots of $1-t^2=0$ are $r_1=1$ and $r_2=-1$. Instead of $c_1$ and $c_2$ I used $a$ and $b$, which is irrelevant, so long as they denote constants.

Comment: Now I got you! Let me check...

Answer (score 0):

Take a Laplace transform to obtain 
$$sF(s)-f(0)=s^3F(s)-s^2f(0)-sf'(0)-f''(0)+\frac{1}{s^2}$$ rearrange 
$$sF(s)-s^3F(s)=f(0)-s^2f(0)-sf'(0)-f''(0)+\frac{1}{s^2}$$
plug for initial conditions
\begin{align}
F(s)&=\frac{4-4s^2-3+\frac{1}{s^2}}{s-s^3}\\
&=\frac{1}{s^3}+\frac{2}{s}+\frac{2s}{s^2-1}
\end{align}
now take an inverse Laplace to obtain

$$f(x)=\frac12x^2+2+2\cosh x$$